# how to pass data from one page to another page in react native using hook (useState)?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

> -------------------- first page -------------------------

```
          const [getName, setName] = useState("")
```

> ```
>  <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
>   <Text>Home Screen</Text>
>   <TextInput placeholder="enter your name"
>   onChange={bob}
>   />
>   <Button
>     title="Next page"
>     onPress={() => {
>       
>       navigation.navigate('Details', {
>        myItem: getName,
>       });
>     }}
>   />
> </View>
> ```
>
> `function bob(input){ setName(input) }`

> ----------------------Second screen ------------------------
>
> <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'
> }}>
>
> ```
>   <Text>itemId:{route.params.myItem}</Text>
> ```
>
> I am facing this error:::
>
> **Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {dispatchConfig, _targetInst, nativeEvent, _dispatchListeners,
> _dispatchInstances, type, target, currentTarget, eventPhase, bubbles, cancelable, timeStamp, defaultPrevented, isTrusted,
> isDefaultPrevented, isPropagationStopped}). If you meant to render a
> collection of children, use an array instead.**

Answer (score 0):

To have global state which can be shared across multiple pages/components you must use **React Context API** along with `useContext` hook.

Refer following link
https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

It is very interesting !
Watch the below video for basic understanding.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sP7ANcTpJr8

Comment: I am unable to pass the data while using context Api. This is my code::::  function Screen2() {
  
    const {getEmail} = useContext(LoginContexts);
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
       
        <Text>{getEmail}</Text>;
   
      </View>
    );
  }  //------------ Screen 2; While following youtube video, my screen becomes blank and there is no error also in console

Comment: you must use 'useContext' in all the pages/component where you want to refer the common state

Comment: I have updated my code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70832433/how-can-i-send-text-taken-from-user-to-another-screen-to-display-it-in-text-in

Comment: I have used 'useContext' in every page still I am facing error please help me. I am a beginner. Not only this but If you also have github code which follows the same concept then please share with me.

Comment: Please watch this playlist then work on code. This will clear all your doubts https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL4cUxeGkcC9hNokByJilPg5g9m2APUePI