# How can I send text taken from user to another screen to display it in <text> in react native? (I am a beginner)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-context

App.js

```js
function App() {
  const [getScreen, showScreen] = useState(false);
  const [getEmail, setEmail] = useState("");

  return (
    <View>
      <LoginScreen />
      <LoginContexts.Provider
        value={{ getEmail, setEmail, getScreen, showScreen }}
      >
        {showScreen ? <Screen2 /> : <LoginScreen />}
      </LoginContexts.Provider>
    </View>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Login

```js
function LoginScreen({ navigation }) {
  const { getEmail, setEmail, showScreen } = useContext(LoginContexts);

  function gotEmail(inputEmail) {
    setEmail(inputEmail);
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.loginText}>Login</Text>

      <View style={styles.textInput}>
        <TextInput
          placeholder="Please enter your email"
          defaultValue={getEmail}
          onChange={gotEmail}
        />
      </View>

      <View style={styles.space} />

      <View style={styles.passwordStyle}>
        <TextInput
          placeholder="password"
          secureTextEntry
          autoCorrect={false}
          autoCapitalize="none"
        />
      </View>

      <View style={styles.space} />

      <View>
        <Button
          style={styles.loginBTN}
          title="Login"
          onPress={() => {
            showScreen(true);
          }}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

export default LoginScreen;
```

Screen 2

```js
function Screen2() {
  const { getEmail } = useContext(LoginContexts);
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
      <Text>{getEmail}</Text>;
    </View>
  );
}

export default Screen2;
```

LoginContext <-- used context api

```js
import { createContext } from "react";

export const LoginContexts = createContext({});
```

Could you please tell me that why data is not going to another page?
I used `useContext` but I am not able to send data to another page. Please help me to solve this problem.

In this I had taken input from user as email and I want to display that email in text view in another page but I am unable to do that. On button click nothing happens.

Comment: If anyone has done this type of functionality then please share me link or code. I am a beginner in this

Comment: Is this approach correct for  sending  data to another page ?